# Firebase dealing with nested data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, say I've got the following FireBase database structure.

```
{
  "2143" :
  {
    "Henk" : 6,
    "message" : 1
  }
}
```

With data being added as follows:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("2143/message");//Testing code, would later be replaced with a session variable and a username variable.
myRef.setValue(1);//Again, mere testing code which sets the 'message' key to have value 1. The actual code is currently lacking as the program isn't entirely functional yet.
```

I now want to put the players and their respective scores into a leaderboard on an android app in android studio. When I'm trying to put them into a hashmap using the following code:

```
    String code = "2143"; //This is would be the SessionID, it's currently static for testing purposes.
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(code);
    HashMap<String, String> leaderboardMap = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    myRef.orderByValue().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                leaderboardMap.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
    }
```

I get the following hashmap

```
key: 2143, value:{Henk=6, message=1}
```

However I expected the following:

```
key: Henk, value: 6
key: message, value: 1
```

Where's the error in my code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please replace the schematic representation of your database with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Like Frank said, we need your json representation and we have to see how your adding the values to firebase too

Comment: Added both in as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the json string to HashMap and then use those values to display in leaderborad. Here is a function to convert json sring to map.

```
public static HashMap<String,String> jsonToMap(String t) throws JSONException {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

        while( keys.hasNext() ){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            String value = jObject.getString(key); 
            map.put(key, value);

        }
        return map;
    }
```